# Placing Google Analytics JavaScript tracking snippet code in www.example.com/gitplaypen/ Vs. www.example.com

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Google Analytics is already working correctly on my website. I am not using the Enhanced Ecommerce plugin yet and I want to use it but first test it from www.example.com/gitplaypen/ before I move it to www.example.com. I placed the Google Analytics JavaScript tracking snippet code in www.example.com/gitplaypen/ for my tests but I am not receiving data yet after almost 48 hours since I placed the snippet code.

Is it possible to test Google Analytics in www.example.com/gitplaypen/ first, or is it required to do it from the root domain www.example.com only? Thank you.

Comment: I already turned on the Enhanced Ecommerce by following the steps at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6032539?hl=en.

Comment: I was reading https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205202?hl=en and summarizing, it says that "Without any modification to the tracking code,....user, traffic, and campaign data to the subdirectory will be shared with user, traffic, and campaign data across the entire website." In my case, the implementation at www.example.com/gitplaypen/ should be tracking data by merging it with the data received from www.example.com, correct?

Comment: What are you trying to test, sending a transaction? Do you have ga snippet installed on both www.example.com and www.example.com/gitplaypen?

Comment: @Confuzing Yes, I am trying to send a transaction and yes, the Google Analytics snippet is installed on both www.example.com and www.example.com/gitplaypen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to upgrade from Google Analytics Ecommerce to Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce and I just used the same code for both www.example.com and www.example.com/gitplaypen/.